# Remote service integrated by library serivce run according to library version

Tags: android, service

i have two application.my remote service is running both app using library.
i want to run single service at time according to library version.
Can anyone tell me how this is posible? Thank you!

Comment: dont place it inside a shared library then

Comment: @pskink  according to need it is not posible.

Comment: @pskink is posible to write meta data version  got by other app.

Comment: what meta data? why do you want to have your service in the library - thus duplicating it on any app that uses that library?

Comment: Android manifest file have option meta data  like google play service meta data